# Error trying to develop middleware using vanilla PHP

Tags: php, json

I just can't seem to get it work. It gets the json and everything, it just doesn't wanna check the request IP.

```
$wl_loc = "whitelist.json";
$wl = json_decode(file_get_contents($wl_loc), TRUE);

function get_client_ip_server() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';

    return $ipaddress;
}

$urip = get_client_ip_server();

foreach($wl as $arr) {
  $ip = $arr['ip'];
  if($urip == $ip) {
    header("Location: /maintenance/");
  }
}
```

and my whitelist.json

```
[
  {
    "ip": "0.123.456.789"
  },
  {
    "ip": "123.456.789.0"
  }
]
```

I've been struggling with this for hours, look all over the internet and I've found nothing. What I want to achieve is by it looping via each IP then checking the request IP then if true don't redirect, else if false then redirect.

Comment: do you mean, you allow only certain IP's and for the rest which are not available in your json list, you put on maintenance? please confirm!

Comment: Yes that is right :)

Comment: did you try on my code in answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try on the below code,

```
$newArray   = array();
$myCallback = function($key) use(&$newArray){
  $newArray[] = $key["ip"];
};
array_walk($wl, $myCallback);
$urip = get_client_ip_server();
if(!in_array($urip, $newArray)) {
    header("Location: /maintenance/");
}
```

a simple logic works here,

created a new array out of the main array, which contains only IP's in a single dimension, and use of `if` statements do the rest.

Comment: I haven't been able to test this because I'm currently out. I'll report back when I'm home.

Comment: Sorry this does not work. Still redirecting me when using my IP.

Comment: Seems like, your ip isn't available into json list.

Comment: It is. I'm using a cloudflare service, which allocates a new IP for every new connection. For example your IP might be: 123.456.789.0 but when you connect to the server, cloudflare hides your IP and it changes your IP to 1.234.567.890